# Download an image from Google Analytics

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, google-analytics

I'm working on a program for automated reporting in Python 3, and I would like to use some charts that Google Analytics provides on its dashboard; for example, the behaviour flow (image below):

[image: Example behaviour flow chart]

I want to insert these charts into the document I'm building.
Would there be a way to download and/or generate images of these charts automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Export -> PDF and later capture the image doesn't works?
If the file will be static could be a rudimentary but valid solution.

Comment: I just noticed that export option. Is there a way that I can get the exported data programatically?

Comment: I think yes, you can program to send a pdf to an email. Follow this link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?hl=en

Comment: I can see that there for the overview, but I can't see an email option for the behaviour flow.